# Lightttpd document root: Changing default page from index.php to xyz.php

Tags: lighttpd

I'm using the Lighttpd webserver in conjuction with PHP.

I'm trying to figure out how to change the default behaviour so that browsing to `"www.domain.com"` would load `xyz.php` instead of `index.php;` both of which are in the doc root.

I was able to add a redirect to lighttpd so that requests to `"www.domain.com/index.php"` are successfully redirected to `"www.domain.com/xyz.php"`.

But I can't figure out how to get `"www.domain.com"` to go to `"www.domain.com/xyz.php"`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've also tried using an alias: "/index.php" =>  document_root + "/xyz.php"
But that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
    url.redirect = (
            "^/$" => "http://www.domain.com/xyz.php"
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic practice is to modify the lighttpd.conf in /etc/lighttpd/, just put xyz.php as the first on in setting **index-file.names** array: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Index-file-names_Details

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `index-file.names` setting in your lighttpd.conf.

```
index-file.names = (
    "xyz.php", "index.php", "index.html"
)
```

In the the above example, a request to `http://www.example.com/` would first serve `xyz.php` if it exists, if not `index.php` and if neither file exists `index.html`

Comment: Duplicate of [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179905/3006854)